# Share HTML fragments between two webapps

Tags: web-applications, tiles, templating

I've been looking for a Java web application library/framework that would allow me to share HTML fragments between two separate webapps running either locally or remotely.

Problem
I have a need to build a website that runs multiple webapps due to size, team structures and release cycles etc (it's common for companies to have multiple apps on their website).
I want to have our main content website to centrally manage the look and feel (headers & footers etc) and have our other webapps consume these HTML fragments. I see it working something similar to sitemesh or Apache Tiles only across remote applications. Has anyone seen anything like this?.. Is there such a framework (EG Apache "Remote" Tiles) ?

Has anybody else tried to tackle the problem of maintaining a consistent look & feel as well as standard content across multiple Java Web applications?

Comment: Is there really no one interested in this problem? I would have thought that it might be a common problem... anyone?